# misuse of continue loop, comparison input in terms of capitalized and lower cased answers

Tags: python, python-3.5

edit:
so just a quick question
So that's great and all, but my concern is what if they type YES and Yes?

```
import sys 
import random 

roll_again = "yes" 


msg=input('Dice Rolling Simulator. Let the dices be ever in your favour. Press ENTER to start our game of luck')
if msg!=input:
  pass

while roll_again == "yes": 
    min = 1 
    max = 6 
    face = random.randint (min,max) 
    print (face)

cmd=input("Would you like to roll the dice again? Type yes if you do.")

if cmd != roll_again : #if it is not 'yes' then system automatically exits.
 print ("One who doesn't throw the dice can never expect to score a six. -Navjot Singh Sidhu")
sys.exit()
```

Sorry, i was quite unsure and probably a bit tired from a previous all nighter.
please help

Comment: The continue statment is used to skip the remaining part of the loop. Could you provide uller example?

Comment: Don't have multiple `if`s. Just convert the inputted string to lower case and compare it to 'yes'. You should show the full loop it's difficult to judge your error from incomplete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

roll_again = "yes"


msg = input('Dice Rolling Simulator. Let the dices be ever in your favour. Press ENTER to start our game of luck\n')

# While the input in lower case is equal to "yes" a dice will be rolled
while msg.lower() == "yes":
    min = 1
    max = 6
    face = random.randint (min,max)
    print (face)
    msg = input("Would you like to roll the dice again? Type yes if you do.\n")

# we get here when the input in lower case is not equal to "yes
print("One who doesn't throw the dice can never expect to score a six. -Navjot Singh Sidhu")
# no need of sys.exit() because system will exit anyway
```

Comment: hello. i tried running the code, and as soon i hit enter, it immediately went to the quote :0

Comment: It works just fine by me. Don't hit enter directly, first write "yes" and then hit the enter. Hitting enter causes the `msg = ""`.

Comment: i see. i understand

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want it to do:

```
import sys
import random

roll_again = "yes"

input("Dice Rolling Simulator. Let the dices be ever in your favour. Press ENTER to start our game of luck")

while True:
    min = 1
    max = 6
    face = random.randint(min,max)
    print(face)

    cmd = input("Would you like to roll the dice again? Type yes if you do.")
    if cmd.lower() != roll_again: #if it is not 'yes' then system automatically exits.
        print("One who doesn't throw the dice can never expect to score a six. -Navjot Singh Sidhu")
        sys.exit()
```

The input for rolling again should be inside the while loop, because what you have now enters an infinite loop and never reaches the second input query.